# menu module created with Features not showing menu links until cache is cleared after Aegir install

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've got Aegir setup and an Install profile created and can create drupal 6.x sites all day long.

My problem is that the top menu feature I created usign the excellent [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features) only shows the menu links once I flush the drupal cache.

The top menu contains menu-top, it's block position (header), and all the menu links.

I am clearing the cache in the install profile

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a menu_rebuild();

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/6